# NSFileManager works when built in Xcode as release, but not when ran as standalone OS X Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsfilemanager

I have the following function written to randomly pick a file from a directory. It works totally fine when I build the project in Xcode for release with the application that automatically opens. However, if I open the application from finder, pressing the button that triggers this function will cause my program to freeze then crash. The only thing I could think of was changing the argument to contentsOfDirectoryAtPath: to not have the ./, but either version has the same exact issue.

Looking at Console tells me that my program exited abnormally with a Floating Point Exception, but I have no idea what's causing it. Is there something jumping out to you guys that I'm not seeing? I only started learning/using objective-C and cocoa about a week ago, so this is all fairly new to me.

Thanks for taking a look at this...

```
- (NSMutableString*)setFilePathRandom{
NSArray* files;
NSFileManager* fileManager;
fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
files = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"./Random Trippy Pics" error:NULL];
NSString* directoryPath = (NSMutableString*)[fileManager currentDirectoryPath];
NSString* fileName;
do{
    fileName = [files objectAtIndex:(arc4random()%[files count])];
}while([fileName isEqualToString:@".DS_Store"]);
filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Random Trippy Pics/%@",directoryPath,fileName];
[fileManager release];
return filePath;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an OS X application is run from Xcode, its current directory is the path to the build folder. When run "normally", the current directory is `/`. So your program is looking for a directory at `/Random Trippy Pics`, which almost certainly doesn't exist. Where is that directory normally?

---

**Edit:**

You could get the directory in which the application is currently stored with this bit of code:

```
NSString *currentStoragePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
```

However, if the `Random Trippy Pics` directory is required by the application, you should store it in a known location -- preferably the application's `Resource` directory. Then you can get the contents with:

```
NSArray *files = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourceOfType:nil inDirectory:@"Random Trippy Pics"];
```

Comment: Oh alright. Thanks so much for helping clear that up for me!

That said, are there any functions that will give me the folder that the application is located within? I essentially have my application, and a folder called "Random Trippy Pics" within the same directory that the application is in.

Comment: Sweet. Thank you so much mipadi! I guess this is the point in time where I learn how to use bundles with Cocoa. I'll have to learn it at some point, and now's as good a time as any. To the Apple developer center it is! I assume that they'll have a tutorial/guide of sorts there.

Comment: @thisissami: The Resource Programming Guide is a good start: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i